# How to copy running-config on the cisco switch

Tags: cisco, switch, linux

i would like to ask how can i copy running-config from my switch to linux, and a ready configurations (with changed values) back to switch but i dont want to use any ftp server or any other method with IP address. I am connected with device via console cable, the device is "clean" and i am using minicom with configurable connection.
Please correct me if I'm wrong, but when i want send already ready configurations can I use the cp command, where gives a target / dev / ttyS0 ? Do replace the Clean configurations?
And does will it work now with the new configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to transfer the file, then you need to use an IP address.

You could always just use the `show running-configuration` command, and copy what is in your terminal to a file. Many terminal applications have a capture feature, or you could just copy-and-paste.

Comment: Ye i know about that, but i wonder how can i send it back. So, i can't upload a new config into my switch ? That switch need the adress ip ?

Comment: You can paste it into the terminal and it is just like typing it in. Text editors and terminal application are used for this every day.

Comment: What if I have a lot  of switches, new switches and each one wants to set up the same way?

Comment: But i want to automate this task later, i just plug in the switch, start up the script and it copy the new config.

Comment: I created an application for use in my company. It creates text files for devices configurations, sometimes many devices. The engineers just open the files in a text editor, copy the configurations, and paste the configurations into the terminal application to configure the devices.

Comment: Ok, can i have one more question ? I trying to copy my config. Enable password and banner doesnt work, When trying log in by "cisco" password it shows bad passwords. I doing it (paste) in configure terminal mode. http://paste.ofcode.org/vHzWN4eXW2htDJsRb8baXP (Sorry, the code is to long :) )

Comment: You must start and end a banner with the same single delimiter character. The way you have it, you are not doing that. Try removing the `C` on the delimiters. It works the same way as if you were typing this in, and you don't type in `^C` as a delimiter. The enable password should work, but you could not telnet to the switch since you don't have a password on the VTY lines.

Comment: Yea, but its still not work. I am connected to the switch via console cable and i have configurate settings on minicom on my virtual machine, so i dont need to set up telnet connection I open session with command minicom. I dont know what i doing wrong, but the password for the enable mode not working, and i need to reset device manually. Thanks for advice

Comment: All I can really see in the difference in what we have is that we don't use the `enable password` command, we use the `enable secret` command to be more secure, and we put a password on all the lines, including `con 0`, `aux 0`, and `vty 0 15`.

Answer (score 0):

TFTP server can be used to copy Configuration from device to pc

Install TFTP server on pc and and connect console cable to switch allocate management ip address to switch

`#copy running-config TFTP`

Can copy Configuration from switch to TFTP server installed on PC

`#copy TFTP runing-config`

This above command allow us to restore Configuration from TFTP to switch .